# Deployment tool with two-factor authentication and code comparison

Tags: gui, remote-access, sftp, two-factor-authentication

I need to access a remote server which has a two-factor authentication (TOTP) for deploy some files.

Commonly, I use the deployment feature from PHPStorm for compare my local code with the remote code and then send the files to the server. Apparently, the PHPStorm [does not have support fro two-facto authentication](https://superuser.com/questions/1022200/phpstorm-sftp-connection-using-two-factor-authenticaton-totp), so I'm looking for a similar tool that works with this type of authentication.

I know that I can use a version control to compare code, but it's not I'm looking for.

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 14.04;

Server configuration:

- CentOS 7.2;